# struct() first number bigger than secound

Tags: c++

So I made a remove function for my list.
How can I make a function that checks -

If first list number is bigger then next one, if so then deletes it and moves it back?

`Input : 1 3 4 2 4 5 2 1 33`

`Output: 1 3 2 4 5 1 33`

```
void remove(node *&head, node *&last){
    if(isempty(head)){
        cout << " Saraksts ir tuksh!"<<endl;    
    } else if (head ==last) {
        delete head;
        head == NULL;
        last == NULL;
    } else {
        node * temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed indenting and some wording. Note- Added closing braces.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do, in the input first list number is `1` which is **not** bigger than the next (which is `3`) one but still a number is deleted from the list. Why is that happened ?

Comment: `head == NULL;` should be `head = NULL;`, the same for `last`.

Answer (score 0):

For singly linked lists, you should maintain a pointer to the previous node.  That way, you can compare the data of the previous node to the present (current node).

To rearrange the order, swap link fields.

I recommend always drawing pictures of nodes when operating with linked lists, something like:

```
+---+     +---+     +---+  
| 5 | --> | 6 | --> | 7 |  
+---+     +---+     +---+
```